# Testing Sidekiq/ActiveJob - Job in ActiveJob but not Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, rails-activejob

I monkey patched my user class (backed by devise) to use ActiveJob like so:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Omitted

  def send_devise_notification(notification, *args)
    devise_mailer.send(notification, self, *args).deliver_later
  end
end
```

I tried testing this with the following test:

```
class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  include ActiveJob::TestHelper

  def setup
    @user = User.new(email: 'example@gmail.com', password: 'password',
                     password_confirmation: 'password')
  end

  test 'send_devise_notification queues into activejob' do
    @user.save
    assert_equal enqueued_jobs.size, 1 # This test passes
    assert_equal Sidekiq::Extensions::DelayedMailer.jobs.size, 1 # This test fails
  end
```

log/test.log looks like this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
UserTest: test_0011_send_devise_notification queues into activejob
------------------------------------------------------------------
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  [1m[36mUser Exists (0.4ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'example@gmail.com' LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mUser Load (0.3ms)[0m  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."confirmation_token" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["confirmation_token", "62d1fac8e1319c29bfbe630aece15975963994b09746edbad65772e4598aa4d2"]]
  [1m[36mSQL (0.4ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "users" ("email", "encrypted_password", "created_at", "updated_at", "confirmation_token", "confirmation_sent_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"[0m  [["email", "example@gmail.com"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$04$b6/WjVWCthq.bKG1KN8JPeb3w8jz8oVWTU53BpTn90wIlTQ5cC2KO"], ["created_at", "2015-01-30 06:19:03.531310"], ["updated_at", "2015-01-30 06:19:03.531310"], ["confirmation_token", "62d1fac8e1319c29bfbe630aece15975963994b09746edbad65772e4598aa4d2"], ["confirmation_sent_at", "2015-01-30 06:19:03.730092"]]
[ActiveJob] Enqueued ActionMailer::DeliveryJob (Job ID: 9730d5a8-5dd4-4334-8290-e4e8e554715e) to Test(mailers) with arguments: "Devise::Mailer", "confirmation_instructions", "deliver_now", gid://swyp/User/232633312, "s7QVW_T2Aw8-ik6o1g2f", {}
  [1m[35m (0.2ms)[0m  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  [1m[36m (0.2ms)[0m  [1mROLLBACK[0m
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  BEGIN
```

enqueued_jobs inside of a debugger looks like this:

```
[{:job=>ActionMailer::DeliveryJob,
:args=>["Devise::Mailer", "confirmation_instructions", "deliver_now", #<User id: 232633312, email: "example@gmail.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$04$E05.gR8oXSHQyk8hUOTBZ.PvswvHy2YYtTNXaha.wj2...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, confirmation_token: "cba7134de82b6fde115fd3ca8e40975befeac299a1e619cdcb...", confirmed_at: nil, confirmation_sent_at: "2015-01-30 17:08:51", unconfirmed_email: nil, created_at: "2015-01-30 17:08:51", updated_at: "2015-01-30 17:08:51", first_name: nil, last_name: nil>, "QBLzzPLKVLy3znSZESBc", {}], :queue=>"mailers"}]
```

bin/rails c --environment test

```
irb(main):004:0> Rails.application.config.active_job.queue_adapter
=> :sidekiq
```

My Procfile looks like this:

```
web: bin/rails s
redis: redis-server
worker: bundle exec sidekiq -q default -q mailers
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ActiveJob::TestHelper` doesn't actually pass the job to the adapter. If you remove it, it'll be an instance of `ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::SidekiqAdapter::JobWrapper`.

Comment: Unfortunately, `assert_equal ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::SidekiqAdapter::JobWrapper.jobs.size, 1` still fails. Any other ideas?

Comment: Mike was right that Sidekiq its an instance of ActiveJob. However, it turns out a nuance of the `ActiveJob::TestHelper`is that doesn't actually add anything directly to the adapter's queue. Removing `ActiveJob::TestHelper` made the second test pass. I've updated his answer to reflect this.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing https://medium.com/@chuckjhardy/testing-rails-activejob-with-rspec-5c3de1a64b66

Answer (score 1):

In testing the default adapter is a `TestAdapter` (see in your logs: [ActiveJob] Enqueued ActionMailer::DeliveryJob (Job ID: 9730d5a8-5dd4-4334-8290-e4e8e554715e) to Test(mailers) with arguments...).

`enqueued_jobs` and other helpers provided by `ActiveJob::TestHelper` are querying the `TestAdapter` and only works if you are using the TestAdapter in testing.

So your first test passes as jobs are handled by the `TestAdapter` but your 2nd test won't pass as the jobs from the `TestAdapter` will never reach Sidekiq.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I marked Mike's answer as the solution because using his answer, I was able to debug the problem first. Have a +1 because if I saw your answer first, it would have solved the issue for me.